# applying the chain rule for taking the derivative w.r.t a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I have the following net $z=Wa$, where $z$ is a column vector `2X1`, $a$ is a column vector of `3X1` and $W$ is a weight matrix with dimensions `2X3`, and a loss function $l=L(z)$ where l is a scalar.

I'm now trying to calculate $\frac{dL}{dW}$ = the derivative of the loss w.r.t $W$, and I'm expecting the dimensions of the result to be `2X3`. How do I do that using the [generalized chain rule](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/%7Eross/Documents/Chain.html)?

1. I calculated $\frac{dL}{dz}$, which is a `1X2` row vector.
2. I calculated $\frac{dz}{dW}$, which is a 3-d array, see below

My professor told us without proof that $\frac{dz}{dW}$ is simply $a$ as a `1x3` row vector!!!, so we can calculate the derivative using a simple outer product: $\frac{dL}{dz}^T\frac{dz}{dW}$, which indeed works out, and looks nice just like the chain rule - but why is that correct? how come my 3-d array below amount simply to $a$?

Looking for a formal explanation, along the lines of [vector-derivatives](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf)

[image: dz/dW]

Answer (score 4):

$\def\p{\partial}$
First of all you are correct: the quantity $\left(\frac{\p z}{\p W}\right)$
is definitely a third-order tensor. The field of machine learning is full of folks (even professors) who use atrocious mathematics.

Second (as you have discovered), it is very difficult to apply the chain rule in matrix calculus because it requires intermediate quantities which are third and fourth order tensors. No one cares about these intermediate quantities, because the final result is always a scalar, vector, or matrix.

A simpler approach is to use differentials, because the differential of a matrix has the same dimensionality as the matrix, and it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra.

One piece of notation that makes things less error prone (especially transpose errors) is the trace/Frobenius product (denoted by a colon) between two equally-sized matrices, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB) = \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij}$$
The properties of the trace allow such products to be rearranged
in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= A:C^TB = C:BA^T \\
}$$
This product also works for vectors (simply think of them as rectangular matrices)
$$a:b = {\rm tr}(a^Tb) = a^Tb \\$$
Assume we have a quadratic loss function
$$L = \tfrac 12 (z-\hat z):(z-\hat z)$$
and wish to calculate its gradient with respect to $W$.
Start by calculating the differential
$$\eqalign{
dL &= \tfrac 12d(z-\hat z):(z-\hat z)+\tfrac 12(z-\hat z):d(z-\hat z) \\
   &= (z-\hat z):d(z-\hat z) \\
   &= (z-\hat z):dz \\
   &= (z-\hat z):dW\,a \\
   &= (z-\hat z)a^T:dW \\
}$$
Now the gradient is easily identified as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p L}{\p W} &= (z-\hat z)a^T \\
}$$
But now you understand the origin of the $a^T$ term. It comes from rearranging a Frobenius product. It is definitely **not** equal to $\left(\frac{\p z}{\p W}\right)^T$

Notice that this gradient has the same dimensions as the $W$ matrix, exactly as you anticipated. This is due to the presence of the $dW$ factor on the RHS of the Frobenius product, which has the **same** dimensions as $W$.

The standard text for this stuff is *Matrix Differential Calculus*
by Magnus & Neudecker.

Comment: wow! thanks - much to take in, I didn't know the trace/Frobenius product. 
i think that you meant $tr(ab^T)=a^Tb$ (the trace of the outer product is equal to the inner product)

Comment: also, why can you do this `rearranging a Frobenius product` to get the expression for $\frac{dL}{dW}$? can you simply divide by $dW$?